# Images/Icons in EXTJS Tree code

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to do a tree in EXTJS.(Ex: `World > Continents > Country > States` ), but i don't have that much idea to make it.

What is this `'icon-basket'`?

Answer (score 0):

simple way:
Just look at this [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/tree/xml-tree.html).
If you want icons - just add `"icon":"http://url.rl/rl"` at your JSON for each node of tree.

Comment: I couldn't find the HTML file. By the way,how does the image change ? like when i click on the node,it changes to another image.